# QField app "updates" my mbtiles and clogs up my storage

Tags: raster, qfield-cloud

I have an issue with my QField app "updating" my mbtiles to the cloud. I only have 100mb as I'm waiting to have it set up before sorting out my company paying for the Pro subscription.

So when I push an update from my QField app it seems to include my mbtiles so now the cloud has 2x55mb files on and it stops functioning.

I have lost only a small amount of data because of this but how can I tell QField not to update my mbtiles layer when it's already set as uneditable?

It does the same with other files, uploading a new version of just background layers that haven't been edited.

Once I upgrade to 1gb this won't be as much of an issue.

I don't need 3 version histories of an unchanging orthophoto on my tiny cloud.